# Different SVG Output for mathematics symbols with dvisvgm used with htlatex or make4ht

Tags: tex4ht, svg, dvi, make4ht, dvisvgm

The tex file with the following code is to be converted into html.

```
\documentclass{article}
    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
    \begin{document}
    \(\implies\) and \(\iff\) \\
    \(a \implies b\) \(a \iff b\)
    \end{document}
```

The command

```
htlatex texfile "xhtml,svg"
```

is  used to convert tex file into html. 
The symbols `\implies` and `\iff` get converted into svg images. The produced svg images are different for these symbols as seen in the attached image. How can this be solved?

[image]

Comment: There is any examples at this link: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/43772/latex-xhtml-with-tex4ht-bad-quality-images-of-equations

Comment: It should be sufficient to add option `--exact` to the call of dvisvgm in your `tex4ht.env`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit:

As Martin mentioned in the comments, some glyphs may exceed it's bounding box, which may result in a cropping of theirs parts. It is possible to tell `dvisvgm` to trace the actual glyph shape using `--exact` option. I will update `tex4ht` to use it. In the meantime, you may use a following `.mk4` build file:

```
Make:image("svg$", "dvisvgm -n -p ${page} --exact -c 1.4,1.4 -s ${source} > ${output}")
```

The result:

[image]

Original answer:

It seems that `dvisvgm` sets wrong dimensions for some images, as it happens for standalone arrows in your example. It seems that height of the first two images is too small, so the image is cropped.

The height of the first image is `3.26027pt`, vs `9.6859pt` of the third one. It is clear that the height difference isn't as big.

I guess that the best solution would be to fix `dvisvgm`, but in the meantime, it is possible to use `make4ht` filters to guess the correct height value. The characters are saved in the `SVG` file as `<path>` elements:

```
<path d='M7.23288 -3.25778C7.65131 -2.89913 8.1594 -2.6401 8.48817 -2.49066C8.12951 -2.33126 7.64134 -2.07223 7.23288 -1.72354H0.9066C0.737235 -1.72354 0.547945 -1.72354 0.547945 -1.52428S0.727273 -1.32503 0.896638 -1.32503H6.78456C6.30635 -0.86675 5.78829 0.00996264 5.78829 0.139477C5.78829 0.249066 5.91781 0.249066 5.97758 0.249066C6.05729 0.249066 6.12702 0.249066 6.16687 0.169365C6.37609 -0.209215 6.65504 -0.737235 7.30262 -1.31507C7.99004 -1.92279 8.65753 -2.19178 9.17559 -2.34122C9.34496 -2.401 9.35492 -2.41096 9.37484 -2.43088C9.39477 -2.44085 9.39477 -2.47073 9.39477 -2.49066S9.39477 -2.53051 9.38481 -2.55044L9.35492 -2.57036C9.33499 -2.58032 9.32503 -2.59029 9.13574 -2.65006C7.79078 -3.04857 6.79452 -3.95517 6.23661 -5.02117C6.12702 -5.22042 6.11706 -5.23039 5.97758 -5.23039C5.91781 -5.23039 5.78829 -5.23039 5.78829 -5.1208C5.78829 -4.99128 6.29639 -4.12453 6.78456 -3.65629H0.896638C0.727273 -3.65629 0.547945 -3.65629 0.547945 -3.45704S0.737235 -3.25778 0.9066 -3.25778H7.23288Z' id='g0-41'/>
```

Every second number in the path is `y` coordinate. My naive approach is to process all `y` coordinates in the `svg` file, find the maximal value and set the height of the image to this value, if it is bigger than the original value. This approach isn't really robust, because curve sections may be rendered above the maximal coordinate, but I don't know how to solve this issue and I don't want to write proper SVG path parser. So we will hope that this doesn't matter much.

Save the following file as `mybuild.mk4`:

```lua
local filter = require "make4ht-filter"

local max = function(a,b)
  return a > b and a or b
end

local function get_height(svg)
  local height = svg:match("height='([0-9%.]+)pt'")
  return tonumber(height)
end

local function get_max_height(path,max_number)
  local coordinates = {}
  for number in path:gmatch("(%-?[0-9%.]+)") do
    table.insert(coordinates, tonumber(number))
  end
  for i = 2, #coordinates, 2 do
    max_number = max(max_number, coordinates[i])
  end
  return max_number
end

local function update_height(svg, height)
  return svg:gsub("height='.-pt'", "height='"..height .."pt'")
end

-- we need to fix the svg height
local process_svg = filter {function(svg)
  local max_height = 0
  local height = get_height(svg)
  for path in svg:gmatch("path d='([^']+)'") do
    -- find highest height in all paths in the svg file
    max_height = get_max_height(path, max_height)
  end
  -- update the height only if the max_height is larger than height set in the SVG file
  print(max_height, height)
  if max_height > height then
    svg = update_height(svg, max_height)
  end
  return svg
end}

Make:match("svg$", process_svg)
```

Compile the file using command

```
make4ht -u -e mybuild.mk4 texfile svg
```

This is the rendered result:

[image]

Comment: The reason for the incorrect heights is that by default dvisvgm uses the character dimensions from TFM files to compute the bounding box. Since some glyphs may exceed their TFM box, the SVG graphics can be clipped in some cases. To avoid this, call dvisvgm with option `--exact`.

Comment: @Martin thanks, I missed that option, it works perfectly!

Comment: @martin what do you think about bounding box issue with TikZ diagrams from this answer: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386775/2891 ?

Comment: Would you please create tag for dvisvgm? It would be nice to post question with tag dvisvgm for issues related to dvisvgm...

Comment: @michal.h21 as far as I can tell, the dvisvgm driver of TikZ doesn't add the required `bbox` specials together with the raw SVG fragments in order to update the bounding box accordingly. It might help to use the dvips driver instead, as dvisvgm also understands PostScript specials. I haven't tested that, though.

Comment: @Martin thanks, `dvips` seems to work in some instances, but for example the test file in the answer linked above produces error `PostScript error: undefined in pgfo`.

Comment: The question https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/194126/did-one-manage-to-get-the-new-dvisvgm-driver-from-pgf-3-0-to-work may be useful

Comment: @michal.h21Yes, I can confirm the issue. The definition of PS operator `pgfo` is missing in the `.idv`file. When using `pgfsys-dvips.def` directly together with LaTeX everything works. So, htlatex somehow omits the PGF PostScript header that's supposed to go into the DVI files.

Comment: @Martin I see. It seems to work when I explicitly add the definitions from `\pgfsys@atbegindocument` to `\pgfsys@beginpicture`, so it is saved in the `.idv` file. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Martin I've updated https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386775/2891 with `pfgsys-tex4ht.def` which seems to work correctly with `dvisvgm`

Comment: @michal.h21Great. I'm glad to hear the information helped to fix the issue.